# Node JS Query request.query is Empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a ReactJS front end and I'm making a fetch call to my NodeJS with Express backend to get data returned. I'm deploying the nodejs app to Firebase Cloud Functions. The url I'm using for the fetch request has parameters in but the query appears to be empty in nodejs.

React JS fetch request:

```
export const nodeJSFetch = async () => {
    const url =
        'https://project-node-js.firebaseapp.com/users?&userId=j872as3';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(proxyURL + url);
        const json = await response.json();

        return Promise.resolve(json);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};
```

NodeJS with Express Function:

```
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
    const query = request.query;
    const json = { user: query, hello: 'new response' };
    response.json(json);
});
```

When I run the Node JS locally and access the url with `http://localhost:5000/users?&userId=j872as3` I get the following JSON returned:

```
{ 
   "user":{ 
      "userId":"j872as3"
   },
   "hello":"new response"
}
```

When I get the JSON back from the fetch I get any empty query/user:

```
{ 
   "user":{},
   "hello":"new response"
}
```

I'm just wondering what I'm missing here and why the query appears to be empty. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `proxyURL + url` trying to do?  What's the final string?

Comment: what is proxyURL ?

Comment: @DougStevenson the proxy url is proxy I'm using to make fetch calls through to solve for CORS `https://project-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://project-node-js.firebaseapp.com/users?&userId=j872as3` is the final url string

Comment: The issue might be in the proxy. Could you please share the code of the proxy?

Comment: @JoseV I ended up removing the proxy and just enabling cors on the node js response. I get a response back but still no `request.query` value

Answer (score 0):

& is used if the backend system has more than 1 query, and is used as the conjunction between one query with another.

My suggestion is remove the &, then test it again.

https://project-node-js.firebaseapp.com/users?userId=j872as3

Comment: It still says site not found

Comment: If you test it on your local computer, and it works, then I think the problem is with the deployment.

because when I try to access the URL https://project-node-js.firebaseapp.com from my own computer it says Site Not Found too.

Comment: @YashKaranke the site works but I had to change the URL for client confidentiality purposes. The url does return the response with the correct param. I tested it with removing the `&` and still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using Axios. When I do it with Axios with the params within the url then the query is still empty. When I construct a request like this it works.

```
    axios
        .get('https://project-node-js.firebaseapp.com/users', {
            params: {
                userId: 'j872as3'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('Axios Response: ', response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Axios Error: ', error);
        });
```

I'm still not very clear on the why behind this though, especially since the URL is the same within the network requests.